# Issue with EPSON, couldn't find "libepos2.so"

Tags: android, fatal-error, thermal-printer, epson

**EPSON network printer was working perfect until I integrated mSwipe(Card Swiper) with my Android App.**

After integration now `mSwipe` working perfectly but everything about `EPSON` is crashing.

`libepos2.so` is there in `src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libepos2.so` but still it says couldn't find.

**`log` below:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.intuition.dine.ivepos, PID: 10908
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.intuition.dine.ivepos-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.intuition.dine.ivepos-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.intuition.dine.ivepos-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libepos2.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:972)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1567)
        at com.epson.epos2.discovery.Discovery.<clinit>(Discovery.java:20)
        at com.epson.epos2.discovery.Discovery.start(Discovery.java)
        at com.intuition.dine.ivepos.SearchIPActivity.onCreate(SearchIPActivity.java:191)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6955)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solved :** I have some more `.so` files which are inside `app/libs/armeabi`.

So, I moved them to `app/src/main/jniLibs` (Just like below Image)

[image: EPSON provided data]

Also, below code in app level `Gradle` inside `defaultconfig{}`

```
ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi"
        }
```

And

```
android{
     splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            universalApk true
        }
    }
}
```

This worked like charm.

Comment: Did you find any way to make it work for emulator (x86)? I can't find the libepos2.so (or sources) compiled for this architecture. Thanks!

Comment: Be aware, Epson Android SDK does not seem to work on the Android emulator. I spent a couple of hours trying to figure out why I had this UnsatisfiedLinkError. Just before I gave up I saw one comment stating this does not work on the emulator, only on real device.

Answer (score 2):

I tried everything in the answers here (and from other questions on stackoverflow), but the only fix for me was making a folder in `app/src/main/jniLibs` called `armeabi-v7a` and copying the so files from `armeabi` to it.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your app level `gradle` file, clean, rebuild and try again.

```
android {
    //Other stuff here
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            universalApk true
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: Still has same issue.